# D3.js Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,NaN)"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to build a data visualization with d3 and I am running into the following error in my console.

```
Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,NaN)".
```

I have taken inspiration from this Plunker and tweaked a few things to make it compatible with my own data.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/FiUrNHNMAXd7EBpr5uY5?p=preview&preview
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

My index.html is exactly the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.9/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my script.js

```
var width = 960,
height = 500,
padding = 1.5, // separation between same-color nodes
clusterPadding = 6, // separation between different-color nodes
maxRadius = 100;
minRadius = 1;


d3.csv("modified_data_happy.csv", function(data) {
m = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.city_index});
console.log("m", m);
color = d3.scale.category10()
.domain(d3.range(m));
clusters = new Array(m);
dataset = data.map(function(d) {
var r = parseInt(d.Happy);
// var r = d.Happy;

var dta = {
  cluster: d.city_index,//group
  name: d.name,//label
  radius: r,//radius
  x: Math.cos(d.city_index / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 100 + width / 2 + Math.random(),
  y: Math.sin(d.city_index / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 100 + height / 2 + Math.random()
  };
  //add the one off the node inside teh cluster
  if (!clusters[d.city_index] || (d.Happy > clusters[d.city_index].radius)) 
  clusters[d.city_index] = dta;

  console.log("dta", dta);

  return dta;
  });
 console.log('dataset', dataset); 
 makeGraph(dataset);
 });


function makeGraph(nodes) {
 var force = d3.layout.force()
 .nodes(nodes)
 .size([width, height])
 .gravity(.02)
 .charge(0)
 .on("tick", tick)
 .start();

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

  var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(nodes)
   .enter().append("g").call(force.drag);

 node.append("circle")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
   return color(d.cluster);
  }).attr("r", function(d) {
  return d.Happy
  })

 node.append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
  return d.name;
  })
  .attr("dx", -10)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
  return d.name
  })
  .style("stroke", "none");

function tick(e) {
  node.each(cluster(10 * e.alpha * e.alpha))
  .each(collide(.5))
  // .attr("transform", functon(d) {});
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var k = "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    return k;
  })

 }

// Move d to be adjacent to the cluster node.
function cluster(alpha) {
return function(d) {
  var cluster = clusters[d.cluster];
  if (cluster === d) return;
  var x = d.x - cluster.x,
    y = d.y - cluster.y,
    l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
    r = d.Happy + cluster.radius;
  if (l != r) {
    l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
    d.x -= x *= l;
    d.y -= y *= l;
    cluster.x += x;
    cluster.y += y;
  }
  };
 }

 // Resolves collisions between d and all other circles.
 function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
  return function(d) {
  var r = d.Happy + maxRadius + Math.max(padding, clusterPadding),
    nx1 = d.x - r,
    nx2 = d.x + r,
    ny1 = d.y - r,
    ny2 = d.y + r;
  quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
      var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
        y = d.y - quad.point.y,
        l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
        r = d.Happy + quad.point.radius + (d.cluster === quad.point.cluster ? padding : 
       clusterPadding);
      if (l < r) {
        l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
        d.x -= x *= l;
        d.y -= y *= l;
        quad.point.x += x;
        quad.point.y += y;
      }
    }
    return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
  });
  };
  }
  }
```

My csv file looks like this (I replaced 'group' with 'city_index, and 'radius' with 'Happy'). That's it.

```
index |       name    | city_index         | Happy -----> Header Row
0     |       Joe     | 3                  | 60   ----->  Data Row
```

So that's where I am right now. I'm not sure why it's not working as the data structures I replaced the example with are the same. I tried removing the parser to no avail. I also tried modifying the "transform, translate" properties as well.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem indicates an SVG element group ( tag  ) has NaN for position coordinates.
I see a problem maybe here in your code :  `.attr("dy", ".35em")`
Try to get rid of the em value and use raw numbers.
I'm not certain it will solve your problem though, if you could post the error in the console and the element it applies to I could help you more.

Comment: I changed the em value and used a raw digit however that code block refers to the text (which I am less interested in).  - It's the circles (nodes) which I really want to populate.

Comment: The best way to solve this would be to trace back to the line that is problematic and log the data passed inside the faulty function. Can you do a console.log of the data on the line that draws circles and see where it fails?
`function tick(e) {
  node.each(cluster(10 * e.alpha * e.alpha))
  .each(collide(.5))
  // .attr("transform", functon(d) {});
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
   console.log("Logging d value : ",d)
    var k = "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    return k;
  })`

Comment: so do a console.log after the ".each()" line I'm assuming, like this console.log("node", node)

Comment: Yes, log the node and the d value associated, I suppose you don't have thousands of nodes right? If yes then reduce the amount so it's easier to target the bug

Comment: [Array(342)]
0: Array(342)
[0 … 99]
0: g
ariaAtomic: null
ariaAutoComplete: null
ariaBusy: null
ariaChecked: null
ariaColCount: null
ariaColIndex: null
ariaColSpan: null
ariaCurrent: null
ariaDescription: null

Comment: however if I do a console.log("k", k) right before the return statement, I get 'translate(Nan, Nan)'

Comment: Yes, because the "d" value is NaN, can you log the "d" value? If it is NaN, it means it has been processed before and you have to go one step before.

Comment: Inside the tick function, just before the line starting in "var k = ....", you can insert a "console.log("D value : ", d). You can notice that d is passed as a parameter to the tick function

Comment: cluster: "6", name: "Zeta Sage", radius: 60, x: NaN, y: NaN, …}
cluster: "6"
index: 341
name: "Zeta Sage"
px: NaN
py: NaN
radius: 60
weight: 0
x: NaN
y: NaN
__proto__: Object

Comment: thats one cluster (of many) that populate

Comment: Could it be that your CSV doesn't have x and y columns?

Comment: my csv does not contain x & y columns - however neither does the csv included in the example

Comment: I'm still trying to find out what's happening. Can you send me your csv?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225685/discussion-between-bullybear17-and-hubert-hilczer).